# Highest speed of operation [BJT vs MOSFET]

Tags: mosfet, bjt, speed

This question was asked in a competitive exam in India.

Which of the following offers highest speed of operation?

(a) BJT

(b) FET

(c) Enhancement Mode MOSFET

(d) Depletion Mode MOSFET

As far as I know, the speed of operation depends on application. In some applications, MOSFET is faster that BJT, whereas in some other applications BJT beats MOSFET. So this questions appears little incomplete to me. The paper setter has given (c) as the correct option.

I wish to challenge this question. Please let me know your views regarding this question. References to any standard textbook will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: (d) **Dep**l**e**tio**n** Mo**d**e MO**S**FET (emphasis mine). The question should at least include a few boundary conditions such as current/power.

Comment: Given how many parts there are that would sort in under either BJT or MOSFET, it's pretty much impossible to answer. The question might as well ask "which is largest, a resistor or a capacitor"... and the answer to that question as well is: it depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would answer (c) because I would think that's what they're looking for but it's a stupid question.

You can make [SiGe bipolar transistors](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/white-paper/SIGE_FACT_SHEET.pdf) (on a chip) with ft's approaching 100GHz, and 4000 series CMOS (enhancement mode MOSFETS) that struggle to switch at 5MHz with low supply voltage. Eg. [4013B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4013b.pdf)

Comment: are they really looking for that answer? Because I've learned that you build RF amplifiers out of BJT, as charging/discharging gate capacitances quickly becomes speed-limiting… But yeah, classical examination style question. It doesn't matter what's correct or whether you understand that "it's not that easy", someone looked into "what we've been teaching", and then just isolated some statement from that…

Comment: @MarcusMüller The OP actually says it's the answer they were looking for. A lot of this stuff is dated too. At any given point in time, one or another technology appears to be clear winner. I recall an IC designer friend saying that designing GHz RF circuits in SiGe was like designing audio with discrete components.